# Data structure to hold and later combine sparse data

Tags: java, data-structures, java-8

Need advice for building the below data structure

```
M                  M
A1       A2        A3        A4       A5
a                  b                  c
a                  b          d        
a         e        b           
a         f        b
```

my data will look like following. Columns marked as `M` together make a unique row. Now i should be able to read a csv line and add a row to the above data structure. If i encounter same unique row again i need to somehow merge the same unique row and the last same uniqe row will win and inherit values for missing values.

Like for above example

i have multiple rows which are same unique row since all the fields marked with `M` are same. So the final table from the above table should like below

```
M                  M
A1       A2        A3        A4       A5
a        f         b         d        c
```

What i want to know if there any data structure to hold such structure ? I dont want to reinvent new ? Also if i can achieve this by some some map and list combination. The headers (A1, A2, A3) are dynamic and are unknown. I read one line from CSV using csv reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HashMap where the key is the concatenation of all the M columns. The only trick would be to use a join separator that cannot appear in any of the M columns so as to avoid the problem resulting from one or more M columns having a null value.

As you get data from the CSVReader, you would do this:

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hm = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
while (csvreader.hasNext()) {
   String line = csvreader.lineReader().readLine();
   String[] fields = csvreader.parser.parseLine(line);
   String key = fields[0] + ":" + fields[2];
   ArrayList<String> exists = hm.get(key);
   if (exists == null)
      hm.put(key, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fields)));
   else
      for (int i=0; i<fields.length; i++) // works only if lines are homogeneous
          if (fields[i] != null && fields[i].length() > 0)
             exists.set(i, fields[i]);  // set values only if they're not null
}
```